# Calculate camera move distance perpendicular to a scene in 3D plane

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx, rendering, direct3d

I have a 3D scene rendered on a texture with vertical field of view FOV, and viewport( 0, 0 , width, height ).  Initially camera is positioned at center of scene. I want to move the camera ( perpendicular to look at direction such that it starts pointing at c1, c2( in image space ). How do I calculate move distance in eye coordinates?
Initial camera parameters – Up vector ( 0, 1, 0), LookAtPoint ( 0, 0, 0 ), CameraPosition( 0, 0, 2 )

[image]

Comment: i think you should move the camera in ((c1, c2) - (w/2, h/2)).normalize() direction untill the x axis of the camera hits the point (c1, c2)

Comment: @ampawd: You method is an aproximation. If the two pixels are far enough from the camera, there can be a large range of values which will be equaly projected into the same pixel. However, it can be enough for the OP.

Comment: @ampawd  what does "x axis of the camera hits the point (c1, c2)" really mean? just want to show a pan effect where scene moves in image space by drag distance, and I was wondering if I can achieve this my moving the camera...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a perspective projection, you don't know the Z value of pixels on the screen. There are infine Z values for a (x,y) position on the screen.

 Projecting different points (xp,yp,yp) by changing only their "zp" produces different (x,y) on screen. And changing xp,yp produces also different x,y on screen.

Think of the steps in a ladder. They look smaller as they get far from your eye. If you don't know in advance the measure of a step, you can not get it just from a picture.

You want to move the camera (on its X-axis) an unknown distance, because you don't know the **real** distance (in world space) between those two pixels on screen.

Comment: I know it's not really possible to measure this accurately..but is there any kind of approximation I can do? I just want to show a pan effect where scene moves in image space by drag distance, and I was wondering if I can achieve this my moving the camera...I didn't really understand ampand approximation..@ampawd or @rip2 what does "x axis of the camera hits the point (c1, c2)" really mean?